# Asymptotic complexity python

Tags: python, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I have a task to find asymptotic complexity of this python code.

```
for i in range(x):
    if i == 0:
        for j in range(x):
            for k in range(500):
                print("A ")
```

By what I know it should be 500*x. Because the first cycle only goes once (i==0), second one goes x times and third one 500 times, so therefore it should be 500*x, shouldn´t it? However this isn´t the right answer. Could you help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: Who is telling you it isn't the right answer? Can you ask them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asymptotic complexity describes the growth of execution time as the variable factors grow arbitrarily large.  In short, constants added or multiplied don't count at *all*, since they don't change with the variable.

Yes, there are 500*x lines printed.  You also have x-1 non-functional loop iterations.  Your total time would be computed as something like

> (x-1)*[loop overhead] + x*[loop overhead] + 500*x[loop overhead + print
>   time]

However, the loop overhead, being a constant, is insignificant, and dropped out of the complexity expression.  Likewise, the 500 is merely a scaling factor, and is also dropped from the expression.

The complexity is **O(x)**.

Answer (score 0):

It's 501*x since you also have to check **x** times the line `if i == 0`.

As the other answer says, usually we don't include the factor. But sometimes we do.